# Parsing JSON without quoted keys

Tags: ruby, json

I understand that in JSON, keys are supposed to be surrounded in double quotes. However, I'm using a data source which doesn't quote them, which is causing the Ruby JSON parser to raise an error. Is there any way to perform 'non-strict' parsing?

Example:

```
>> JSON.parse('{name:"hello", age:"23"}')
JSON::ParserError: 618: unexpected token at '{name:"hello", age:"23"}'
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.1.7/lib/json/common.rb:122:in `parse' 
    from /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/json-1.1.7/lib/json/common.rb:122:in `parse'
    from (irb):5
>> JSON.parse('{"name":"hello", "age":"23"}')
=> {"name"=>"hello", "age"=>"23"}
>>
```

(I tried using a regular expression to add the quotes in before parsing but couldn't get it fully working).

Comment: If it's not JSON, it's not JSON. It might superficially resemble it, but the correct solution is to fix the source so it actually gives JSON isntead of something-that-looks-a-bit-like-JSON-but-isn't.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no control over the source, it's from a third party.

Comment: I think what you have there is YAML, not JSON. So use a YAML parser.

Comment: http://www.google.com/ig/calculator?hl=en&q=100AUD=?USD for instance requires what he is asking for. @floyd has the solution below - and is acceptable

Comment: Does Ruby's JSON library have a non-strict mode? IIRC, Perl's JSON CPAN module will parse that, as it allows Javascript-but-not-JSON like you have above.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If the data is pretty well formed other than that, a simple regex might do it:

```
irb(main):009:0> '{name:"hello", age:"23"}'.gsub(/([a-z]+):/, '"\1":')
=> "{\"name\":\"hello\", \"age\":\"23\"}"
```

Comment: `'{name:"hello", age:"23"}'.gsub(/([\w]+):/, '"\1":')` makes it a little more robust!

Comment: Fails miserably if the value is a timestamp. For example { name: "Hello", time: "12:59:59" }

Answer (score 9):

I have this same issue with a third party data feed, but mine returns a more complicated JSON-like response which the gsub solutions don't handle. After some research it appears these data feeds are actually JavaScript object literals which don't require the keys to be quoted.

To resolve the issue I added the execjs gem and installed node.js (therubyracer gem would probably work as well). Once complete, the following returns a correctly parsed ruby hash.

```
ExecJS.eval('{name:"hello", age:"23"}')
 => {"name"=>"hello", "age"=>"23"}
```

Answer (score 7):

Interestingly, your example is valid ruby 1.9 Hash syntax. If your data is really as simple as this (no spaces or other special characters in the key names), and you can process it in a safe context, you can just `eval` it.

```
irb(main):001:0> eval '{name:"hello", age:"23"}'
=> {:name=>"hello", :age=>"23"}
```

This gives you symbols as keys, so post-process if you need to turn them into strings:

```
irb(main):002:0> eval('{name:"hello", age:"23"}').reduce({}) {|h,(k,v)| h[k.to_s] = v; h}
=> {"name"=>"hello", "age"=>"23"}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, although since I'm using 1.8.7 that's not an option at the moment.

Comment: Very clean solution! Thanks. Much cleaner to leverage this information from Google rather than hunting down another gem.

Comment: This can be very dangerous... (e.g. if you get from the server `{a: 1}; \`rm -rf /\``)

Comment: Old thread, but to @ghayes' concern: eval("[..]".gsub("`", "'"))

Answer (score 2):

```
gsub(/(\w+)\s*:/, '"\1":')
```

worked better than

```
gsub(/([a-z]+):/, '"\1":')
```

If it had spaces or capital letters, it failed.

Answer (score 1):

(Answering my own question) The snippet that floyd posted was similar to what I tried - it was failing because some of my strings contain colons. But I persisted and found a solution:

```
gsub(/([\{|\,}])\s*([a-zA-Z]+):/, '\1 "\2":')
```

Comment: The problem is your regex will as well replace instances of "key=" inside a quoted value, which one don't want.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I have had to solve it:

```
JSON.parse(broken_json_string.gsub(/'([^']+)':/, '"\1":'))
```

Some of the above assumes the keys only contain letters; some of ours contained underscores, spaces, etc. Easier to just say "any character that isn't a single quote" (given, in our case, all the keys were wrapped in single quotes).

Answer (score 0):

Actually you could just use a YAML parser, as YAML is basically JSON without using qoutes for keys (while is optionally also allows it).
However it doesn't like not having spaces after the colon (otherwise sees it as one string). But it's still more robust then the regex trying to put qoutes arround arbitraty strings, I think

So this should work:

```rb
require 'yaml'

s = '{name:"hello", age:"23"}'
YAML.load(s.gsub(':', ': '))
```

Also this nicely turns types into ruby types (like integers for numbers), allows for single and double qoutes for strings etc.

For example a this

```rb
YAML.load("{ integer: 123, boolean: false, float: 123.4, string: 'Hello', another_string: \"Double quotes\", array: ['str'] }")
```

returns

```rb
{"integer"=>123, "boolean"=>false, "float"=>123.4, "string"=>"Hello", "another_string"=>"Double quotes", "array"=>["str"]}
```

So it's almost as convenient as using `eval`, without all the security drawbacks that come with using that.