# Unusual syntax JSON parse problem String (Clojure)

Tags: json, string, syntax, clojure

I have a long clojure String (java.lang.String) representing a JSON. It has "normal" looking syntax like so:

```
"{ a:1, b:"hello" }"
```

The keys do not have quotes around them.

All the libraries I have looked at such as [clojure.data.json](https://github.com/clojure/data.json/blob/master/src/main/clojure/clojure/data/json.clj) want this syntax in order to parse into an object:

```
"{\"a\":1,\"b\":"hello"}"
```

Is there a way to parse the top syntax into json or clj objects? Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This isn't a solution for clojure, per se, so not a duplicate, but might give you some ideas:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2060356/parsing-json-without-quoted-keys

Comment: This is not valid JSON, but a JavaScript object. You'll notice when you try it in a validator like https://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: The unfortunate answer is you'll have to parse it yourself. The only (better) answer is to get the source to feed you valid JSON instead.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on your level of desperation, the Groovy JSON Slurper can read this "JSON" in the `LAX` setting (which allows those attributes, comments, ...)

Add the following dep:

```clj
[org.codehaus.groovy/groovy-json "2.5.6"]
```

Then you can run:

```clj
user=> (import [groovy.json JsonSlurper JsonParserType])
groovy.json.JsonParserType
user=> (def parser (doto (JsonSlurper.) (.setType JsonParserType/LAX)))
#'user/parser
user=> (def data (.parseText parser "{ a:1, b:\"hello\" }"))
#'user/data
user=> data
{"a" 1, "b" "hello"}
```

Comment: Nice!  I didn't know that was available from Clojure.

Comment: It's just .class files in a jar... :)

Answer (score 1):

## Update 2019-3-21

The link from @jas includes a comment that "it looks like YAML" (if the colons are followed by a space).

I have integrated the new [snakeyaml-engine](https://bitbucket.org/asomov/snakeyaml-engine) library into [the Tupelo Library](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo).   API docs [are here](https://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.parse.yaml.html).  The answer is now super-simple:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use demo.core tupelo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require [tupelo.parse.yaml :as yaml] ))

(dotest
  (let [data-1 "{ a: 1, b: 'Hello World' }"]
    (is= (yaml/parse data-1) {:a 1, :b "Hello World"})))
```

---

### Old Answer

Given `project.clj`

```
 [io.forward/yaml "1.0.9"]
```

this works:

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:require [yaml.core :as yaml]) )

(def data-1 "{ a: 1, b: \"Hello World\" }" )

  (let [result-raw (yaml/parse-string data-1)
        result     (into {} result-raw)]
```

with result

```
----------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.0    Java 10.0.1
----------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
result-raw   => #ordered/map ([:a 1] [:b "Hello World"])
result       => {:a 1, :b "Hello World"}
```

Unfortunately it (currently) fails under Java 11 because a dependent library needs a type hint.  You can work around this by fixing up your `project.clj`:

```
  :dependencies [
     [io.forward/yaml "1.0.9" :exclusions [org.flatland/ordered
                                           org.yaml/snakeyaml] ]
     [org.yaml/snakeyaml "1.23"]
     [org.flatland/ordered "1.5.7"]
     [org.clojure/clojure "1.10.0"]
```

I filed an issue with the `io.forward/yaml` project to update their dependencies.